# Laravel webpack-mix omitting @import statements from the Minified CSS files

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, minify, laravel-mix

I am trying to Minify the following

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,700,700i,900');
@import 'plugin/bootstrap.css';
@import 'pages/reset.css';
@import 'pages/common.css';
@import 'pages/animations.css';
@import 'pages/form.css';
```

to

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,700,700i,900);@import url(plugin/bootstrap.css);@import url(pages/reset.css);@import url(pages/common.css);@import url(pages/animations.css);@import url(pages/form.css);
```

But for some reason when I run: **npm run prod**. The minified file that I get back only contains the first import statement for google fonts as given below and for some reason, other import statements are omitted from the output:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,700,700i,900);
```

I have written the following in the **webpack.mix.js** file to achieve this:

```
mix.styles('public/assets/css/global.css', 'public/assets/css/global.css');
```

When I use CSS Minifier **(https://cssminifier.com/)** I get the intended output, but I want to do that locally using Laravel mix.

Answer (score 0):

Your Webpack line imports and exports from the same location. Maybe try:

```
mix.styles('resources/sass/global.css', 'public/css');
```